# On server 2008 R2 shutdown not enough time to save all Hyper-V VMs

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 host with lot of VM's on it.

Due to specific usage requirement I need all of the VM's states be saved on server Shutdown but it takes too much time (about 20-25 minutes to save all VM's states). This causes Windows Server to force shutdown after some 10-15 minutes before all of the VM's states were saved.

I can't find anywere is it possible to someway change that delay before Windows Server force shutdown ?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/02/21/use-powershell-to-perform-an-orderly-shut-down-of-a-hyper-v-server.aspx) for a scripted solution

Comment: As I understand it's Windows Server 2012 solution

Comment: From what I can tell the post from @MichelZ should still be applicable to your scenario.  Just make sure you have the same version of PowerShell mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Microsoft has a [KB to reenable the WaitToKill](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549760) registry value for Windows Server 2008 R2. Might try to enable that and see if it works. Enable the registry value to 1500000 to see if 25 minutes is long enough.